# django api for create data in db

Tags: python, django, api, django-models, django-rest-framework

every one, I am trying to wrote an django api to  create data in db ,here is my

#### models.py

```
class ProductsTbl(models.Model):
    model_number = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        blank=True,
        unique=True,
        error_messages={
            'unique': "這 model number 已經被註冊了 ."
        }
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    material = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    feature = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    release = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    twtime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    hktime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    shtime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    jptime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    suggest = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    cataloggroup = models.ManyToManyField(CatalogGroup)
    place = models.ManyToManyField(Place)
    scale = models.ManyToManyField(Scale)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    useredit = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_imagep_Product, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' On save, update timestamps '''

        if not self.id:
            self.created = timezone.now()

        return super(ProductsTbl, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

the views.py I can create data  from form ok

#### views.py

```
def create_thing(request):
    form_class = ProductsTblForm
    # if we're coming from a submitted form, do this
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # grab the data from the submitted form and apply to # the form
        form = form_class(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            # create an instance but do not save yet
            thing = form.save(commit=False)
            # set the additional details
            thing.user = request.user
            thing.slug = slugify(thing.model_number)
            # save the object
            thing.save()
            # redirect to our newly created thing
            return redirect('thing_detail', slug=thing.slug)
    # otherwise just create the form
    else:
        form = form_class()
    return render(
        request,
        'things/create_thing.html',
        {'form': form, 'login_user': request.user}
    )
```

however, when comes to api,,,I jsut fail, here is my

#### api/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   .....
    url(r'^productsTbls/create_thing/$',views.api_create_thing,name='api_create_t'),

]
```

### api/views.py

```
......
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
........



@csrf_exempt
def api_create_thing( user_id ,model_number,name,release,feature, material,image,suggest,description,):
    p1 = ProductsTbl(user_id = user_id ,model_number = model_number,slug = model_number ,name = name ,release = release ,feature = feature, material = material ,image=image,suggest = suggest,description = description )
    p1.save()
    return redirect('/api/productsTbls/')
```

here is my error message

[image]

thanks for any one who reply to me

Comment: You should show your URL; you have written the view to accept 9 parameters from there, but you don't seem to be passing any.

Comment: In the meantime, since you're trying to write an API, why don't you use django-rest-framework which is intended exactly for that purpose?

Comment: right ,, I should try to use django-rest-framework,,,however I am reading it's doc right now,thank you

Comment: But first, please show your urls.py, as I already asked.

Comment: I just add the urls.py in above,,but I want to use POST, do I need add parameters to url?

Comment: So i was right, your URL doesn't capture any parameters, but your view is expecting 9 parameters. Where are they supposed to be coming from?

Comment: Did you try changing your urls.py as suggested in my answer?

Comment: hi,e4c5,thanks for your answer,,,right now ,I am using Django Rest Framework , I can create things ok,,however,I meet another problem,,about serializers ForeignKey and upload images,,,,.http://stackoverflow.com/q/38657178/5678590

Comment: sorry haven't done uploads with DRF so I am not much use for that one :(

Comment: it's ok,,thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `api_create` method seems to be totally redundant and can be deleted safely. Your urls.py should instead point to the `create_thing` method in views.py

```
urlpatterns = [
   .....
    url(r'^productsTbls/create_thing/$',views.create_thing,name='api_create_t'),

]
```

The reason that api_create_thing isnt' needed is because you already have the code to gather the data from the user with a form and save it to db. The second point is that it's not a good idea to use GET method to accept user input. You should always try to use POST (which create_thing) already does.