# Django Rest Framework 3.4 foreign key serialization and upload image file

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

every one, I am working the project (use django 1.8 ) have a ForeignKey, and I have to upload image file through the api,but I just fail to do it,,can any one tell me how to do it,thank you.

within the `models.py` there is a `class Upload(models.Model):` it has the ForeignKey `thing = models.ForeignKey(ProductsTbl, related_name="uploads")`  to `class ProductsTbl(models.Model):`

> models.py

```
class ProductsTbl(models.Model):
    ......
    model_number = models.CharField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    material = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    .......
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' On save, update timestamps '''

        if not self.id:
            self.created = timezone.now()

        return super(ProductsTbl, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


def get_image_path(instance, filename):
    return '/'.join(['thing_images', instance.thing.slug, filename])


class Upload(models.Model):
    thing = models.ForeignKey(ProductsTbl, related_name="uploads")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, verbose_name='Image')

    ..........
```

> api/serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from ..models import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


UserModel = get_user_model()

class ProductsTblSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductsTbl
        fields = ('model_number','name','material',)

class UploadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ProductsTbl = serializers.CharField(source='ProductsTbl.id')
    class Meta:
        model = Upload
        fields = ('thing','image')
    ........
```

> api/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views




urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^productsTbls/$', views.ProductsTblListView.as_view(), name='productsTbls_list'),
    url(r'^productsTbls/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ProductsTblDetailView.as_view(), name='productsTbls_detail'),
    url(r'^Upload/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.UploadDetailView.as_view(), name='Upload_Detail'),
    ......
]
```

> api/views.py

```
from rest_framework import generics
from ..models import *
from .serializers import ProductsTblSerializer,UploadSerializer,UserSerializer
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.forms import modelformset_factory
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny




class ProductsTblListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = ProductsTbl.objects.order_by('-created')
    serializer_class = ProductsTblSerializer



class ProductsTblDetailView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = ProductsTbl.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductsTblSerializer


class UploadDetailView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Upload.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UploadSerializer

......
```

> settings.py

```
........
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
        #'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
    ]
}
.......
```

when I try to upload image through PUT , I just seeing `{"detail":"Not found."}`

[image]

Comment: Have you set the [setting for upload handlers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/file-uploads/)?

Comment: but this is Django Rest Framework,I can upload image from form ok,but I do not know how to upload image from api